# Java Loan Calculator nested for loop based on user input

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested, calculator

The task is to create a loan calculator based on the user input of min and max years of loan payments, loan amount, and min and max % rate with incremented value given by user as well for rate and number of years. 
Desired output should look like this:

Principle: $275000.0
   Years to repay: 10
   Interest Monthly
   Rate Payment

---

6.25 3087.7
   6.75 3157.66
   7.25 3228.53

Principle: $275000.0
   Years to repay: 15
   Interest Monthly
   Rate Payment

---

6.25 2357.91
   6.75 2433.5
   7.25 2510.37

Principle: $275000.0
   Years to repay: 20
   Interest Monthly
   Rate Payment

---

6.25 2010.05
   6.75 2091.0
   7.25 2173.53

Please help me fix errors. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);              

            System.out.println("This program computes monthly " + "mortgage payments.");
            System.out.print("Enter the loan amount:   "); 
            double loan = console.nextDouble(); 

            System.out.print("Enter the starting number of years to repay the loan:   ");
            int startingYears = console.nextInt(); 

            System.out.print("Enter the ending number of years to repay the loan:   ");
            int endingYears = console.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter the years increment between tables:   ");
            int incrementYears = console.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter the starting loan yearly interest rate, %:   ");
            double startingRate = console.nextDouble(); 

            System.out.print("Enter the ending loan yearly interest rate, %:    ");
            double endingRate = console.nextDouble(); 

            System.out.print("Enter the increment interest rate, %:   ");
            double incrementRate = console.nextDouble();            
            System.out.println();               

            System.out.println("Principle: $" + (double) loan);
            System.out.printf("Years to repay: %d\n", startingYears);
            System.out.println("-------- -------");

            double payment;             
                System.out.println("Rate\tPayment");

            for (int j = startingYears; j <= endingYears; incrementYears++) {
            for (double i = startingRate; i <= endingRate; incrementRate++){



                int n = 12 * startingYears;
                    double c = startingRate / 12.0 / 100.0;
                payment = loan * c * Math.pow(1 + c, n) / (Math.pow(1 +c, n) - 1);  

                System.out.println(i + " " + payment);
//              System.out.println(round2(startingRate) + "\t" + round2(payment));
                startingYears += incrementYears;
            }
            }


        }

        }
```

Comment: How do I increment both the counters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for (int j = startingYears; j <= endingYears; incrementYears++) {
>
> for (double i = startingRate; i <= endingRate; incrementRate++) {

You are never incrementing the values of your counters i.e. `i` and `j` and hence the values of `i` and `j` will always be equal to the initialized values and these loops will run for infinite times.

Increment both the counters to be able to reach the termination condition i.e. `j <= endingYears` and `i <= endingRate` respectively.

Here is the code snippet:

```
System.out.println("Principle: $" + (double) loan);
for (int j = startingYears; j <= endingYears; j+=incrementYears) {
    System.out.printf("Years to repay: %d\n", j);
    System.out.println("-------- -------");
    System.out.println("Rate\tPayment");
    for (double i = startingRate; i <= endingRate; i+=incrementRate){
        int n = 12 * j;
        double c = i / 12.0 / 100.0;
        double payment = loan * c * Math.pow(1 + c, n) / (Math.pow(1 + c, n) - 1); 
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + payment);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I am not 100% understanding the suggestion. Do I need to add i += incrementYears?

Comment: for (int j = startingYears; j <= endingYears; j++) {
   for (double i = startingRate; i <= endingRate; i++){
     
    i += incrementRate;
    
    
     int n = 12 * startingYears;
     double c = startingRate / 12.0 / 100.0;
     payment = loan * c * Math.pow(1 + c, n) / (Math.pow(1 +c, n) - 1); 
     
     System.out.println(i + " " + payment);
//     System.out.println(round2(startingRate) + "\t" + round2(payment));
//   startingRate += incrementRate;

    }
    }
    j += incrementYears;

Comment: Updated the solution. Replace everything after `System.out.println("Principle: $" + (double) loan);` in your solution with the above snippet.